# MasterPage issues with anchor tags and fancyBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got some ASP:Hyperlink controls on the master page for a set of global links. I'm using the 'permissions' property so I'm hoping to keep these.

If I setup the control like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="inlineMileageCalc" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/#mileageCalc">Mileage Calculator</asp:HyperLink>
```

Everything works fine when I'm on the default.aspx page in the root. However, if I go down one more level like http://www.xxxxx.com/nextlevel/default.aspx the fancyBox will not render, just throws a jQuery error.

Is there a way to do this to make the fancyBox show no matter what level I'm on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it picking up its required dependencies from relative paths correctly?

Perhaps you're specifying "./scripts/somefile.js" or "scripts/somefile.js", which will break from deeper links. Have you tried using FireBug or similar to see if you're getting any 404s on js or css files?

Comment: Have discovered it is a relative URL issue. I have a work-around, will post it when done.  Thanks.